# How to place the cursor Exact center of the screen

Tags: c#, winforms

How to place the cursor Exact center of the screen in C# ?

without Resolution independent (it can be 1024X768 or 1600X900)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this, assuming you have only 1 monitor:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have DPI set to 150% and Screen.Bounds reports my display as 1280x720 when it is really 1920x1080. So it puts the cursor at (640, 360) instead of (960, 540).

Comment: Found the solution. You have to make it "DPI-aware" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308410.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Start by getting the *Screen* instance of interest. If you only ever want the main monitor then simply ask for the *PrimaryScreen* instance. If however you want the monitor that currently contains the mouse pointer then use the *FromPoint* static method.

```
    // Main monitor
    Screen s = Screen.PrimaryScreen;

    // Monitor that contains the mouse pointer
    Screen s = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);
```

To get the raw monitor bounds then just use the *Bounds* instance property. But if you want the working area of the monitor, the area that is left over after allocating space for the task bar and widgets then use the *WorkingArea* instance property.

```
    // Raw bounds of the monitor (i.e. actual pixel resolution)
    Rectangle b = s.Bounds;

    // Working area after subtracting task bar/widget area etc...
    Rectangle b = s.WorkingArea;
```

Finally position the mouse in the center of the calculated bounds.

```
    // On multi monitor systems the top left will not necessarily be 0,0
    Cursor.Position = new Point(b.Left + b.Width / 2,
                                b.Top + b.Height / 2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the Screen s = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
        var r = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point(r.Bottom/2,r.Right/2);
```